# How to Change the Arrangement of Icons in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, icons

Say for example,

In some folders, I need large view for images.

I have to press <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> (View -> View Options) and set the grid size larger or use Cover Flow View (<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>)

In some folders, I need details view for songs, or my official files, I use list view (<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>) to see details, like date of creation, date of modification, etc. However, view as list doesn't provides all details columns like - owner, author, for all that kind of sorting also not available

Now, whenever I create new folders, for images, I have to apply settings to each of the new folders.

Windows automatically sets thumbnails view, film strip view for images & details view for song.

Does Mac OS X do the same? Is there an option available to set specific settings for a directory in Mac OS X?

Comment: is there any utility available regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finder view options are stored in the `.DS_Store` files.

The Default View Options are read and used whenever a new window is created for that directory (whether it's opening a new window from a directory on your desktop or if you held the <kbd>Command</kbd> button when double clicking on a directory/folder).

If you are browsing between folders the view style will not modify when you switch folders.

So yes, Mac OS X does have the capability but no, it does act like Windows in that it can change the view style while browsing your file system. The workaround is to hold the <kbd>Command</kbd> key when opening a new window. Which is an experience that most most people who didn't use Mac OS 9 and earlier are used to.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the right solution, but after having a Finder window opened and selected, click View -> View Options to bring up many options regarding how this window behaves. In fact, you could click on Use as Defaults to make the changes you made apply to all future windows. Changes to a specific window and stay that way by not clicking Use as Defaults.

The contents of the view options window would dynamically change to show options that are applicable to your current window view (list, column, or icon views, etc.).